# What kind of cable is suitable for ultrabooks?

Tags: cable, ultrabook

I have bought a Ultrabook and found that normal cables for LAN are not suitable for it.

There is a slot which seems to be for cables, but the height is too low.

What is the slot? What kind of cable should I buy?

[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide the specific model and brand of this [ultrabook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrabook)?

Comment: hm, you need to use your macro mode better. I see a small pixelated orc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still the same, a normal [RJ-45 plug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#8P8C):

[image]

As ultrabooks are much thin that a normal notebook, the female connector looks like smaller, a normal female RJ45 plug just wouldn`t fit on the ultrabook depth, so a mobile part was added with a spring that hold the male connector into the female. If you pull down the mobile part you will notive that is still the same.

Comment: In other words, There should be a hinge there to allow a standard rj45 plug... Can you drop the lower portion of the jack to enlarge the opening?

Comment: How to convert a "fat" one to a "thin" one?

Comment: Your connector opens up to fit the larger connector, like a snake unhinging its jaws to eat a goat.